# Convert dynamically created element to DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I'm working with html5 canvas and I'm very confused about the difference between jQuery elements and html elements.

When working with 2d canvas drawings you generally open with

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"); // identifies element
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'); // specifies a 2d rendering context
```

I am using jQuery so I figured I could use the selector

```
var canvas = $("#canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
```

...and the console error returned "canvas.getContext is not a function".  I browsed and learned that .getContext won't run because canvas is now a jQuery object and not a canvas element.  A common solution to this problem is to use...

```
var canvas = $("#canvas").get(0);
```

...which works well for most people to convert a jQuery object back to its native DOM element.  Unfortunately here 'canvas' returns undefined because my canvas element is dynamically generated and not a native DOM element.  I tried...

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
```

...but that returned 'null'.  How do I find a dynamically created canvas element and apply it in this context?  Let me know if I have misunderstood something or if you need more information.

Comment: Why not just save the dynamically created `canvas` element in a variable and then use this variable when the native `canvas` element is needed?

Comment: That also returns "canvas.getContext is not a function".

Comment: How exactly are you creating a `canvas` element dynamically?

Comment: var palette = div.append("<canvas id='canvas' height='" + 100*scale + "px' width='" + 100*scale + "px'></canvas>");

Comment: Then `div.get(0).lastChild` should return the appended `canvas` element.

Comment: I would recommend you to create a live demo that demonstrates the issue. For example, via [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: `var canvas = $('#canvas' , palette )[0] ;`

Comment: A fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/73jz6ebd/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/73jz6ebd/1/) !

```js
function makeColorPalette(scale, div) {
    var palette = div.append("<canvas id='canvas' height='" + 100*scale + "px' width='" + 100*scale + "px'></canvas>");
    var canvas = $('#canvas')[0];
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.fillRect(50, 25, 150, 100);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
 makeColorPalette(2, $('.palette'));
});
```

```css
#canvas {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="palette">
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe a small explanation ?

Comment: `$()` will return a jQuery object.  If you need the element selected in this object, you need either use its `get(index)` method or its `[index]` array index. (`$('#anyElement')[0]` or `$('#anyElement').get(0)` will return the element)

Answer (score 0):

Your example [does](http://jsfiddle.net/73jz6ebd/2/) work if replace `$('#canvas')` with `$('#canvas').get(0)` or with `div.get(0).lastChild`.